# $f'_+(c)=f'(c)=L$

Tags: limits, derivatives

With regard to the question:[$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170285/lim-x-to-c-fx-l)

> **The derivative**:Suppose that $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$, where$ A ⊆ \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in A $ is an accumulation point of  $\{ x\in A : x > c\}$ 
>   and $ c$ is not an accumulation point $\{ x\in A : x < c\}$ Then:
>
> $$f'(c)=L$$
>
> if and only if:
>
> $$f'_+(c)=L$$

is the theorem  correct ?

Answer (score 1):

> A function is differentiable at a point $c$ if and only if the left and right derivative at $c$ exist and are equal.

So, in your case, $f'(c)=L$ iff $f'_-(c)$ exists and $f'_-(c)=f'_+(c)=L$.

And note that the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition) of derivative at a point $c$ require that the function is defined in an **open neighborhood** of $c$.